# Web Service Connection Fails After It is Ported To WCF

Tags: web-services, wcf, apache-axis

I am the developer of an application which is the consumer of an in-house developed web service. The web service was originally developed in Java and deployed in JBoss.

Recently, I have been notified that the web service had been completely ported to .NET WCF. I simply updated the web service endpoint URI string in my configuration file, but my application has failed to connect to the new web service.

Upon comparing the old and new WSDLs, I can see that the methods and the structures are the same, but somehow the namespaces and the internal structures of arrays are different.

What do you suggest so that my application would be compatible with the new web service?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you generate the proxy when the service was originally in Java?  You may need to regenerate the proxy against the new endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace change means the WSDL of both Java Web service and WCF service are different. You know in programming classes of the same name but in different namespaces are totally different classes. Likewise, though the method signatures and data signatures look the same, however, in different XML namespace of WSDL, they are different contracts. Thus on your client side, you should have new set of proxy classes to talk the the WCF service.

You may ask the developers of the Web services about what were the intend of changing Xml namespace in WSDL. If for the co-existence of both Java Web service and Wcf Web service and enforcing some changes on client side, you MUST generated new proxy classes against the new WSDL, and it is recommended to use svcutil.exe rather than Service Reference in IDE so you have fine gained control over CLR namespace mapping to Xml namespace.

If the service developer could reverse the change the Xml namespace of WSDL for good reasons and the WSDL could remain the same, you just need to change only URL.